# Find substitutions (changes of variables) that convert the system into a linear system

Tags: linear-algebra

The system of equations is nonlinear. Find substitutions (changes of variables) that convert the system into a linear system
and use this linear system to help solve the given system.

$$x^2 + 2y^2 = 6$$
$$x ^2 - y^2 = 3$$

I do not need help with the second part. I just do not understand how to do the conversion step.

Comment: Let X = x^2 and Y = y^2. Substitute and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $u=x^2,v=y^2$ to get:

$$\begin{array}{cc} 
u&+&2v&=&6 \\
u&-&v&=&3 \\
\end{array}$$

which can be solved simultaneously.

When you solve for $u,v$ be sure to exclude any solution for which $u<0$ or $v<0$ (will not happen in this case, but in others it is possible), as these do not give valid solutions in $x,y$.